# Set name of output executbale when building Java Native package app?

Tags: java, javafx

How do you set the name of the output executable when building Native Package using `jfx:native`?

Right now, it create the name like `{<name>}+{<version>}`.exe for example `myapp-SNAPSHOT-0.exe`

Is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following way to specify native bundle name, version, architecture (`x86` or `x64`) and additional options:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>osx-x64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
                <name>Mac OS X</name>
                <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <installer.bundler>dmg</installer.bundler>
            <installer.Xmx>-Xmx6G</installer.Xmx>
            <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-x64</installer.packageName>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>windows-x64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
                <arch>amd64</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <installer.bundler>msi</installer.bundler>
            <installer.Xmx>-Xmx6G</installer.Xmx>
            <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-x64</installer.packageName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>windows-x86</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
                <arch>x86</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <installer.bundler>msi</installer.bundler>
            <installer.Xmx>-Xmx1G</installer.Xmx>
            <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-x86</installer.packageName>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>linux-x64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>Linux</name>
                <arch>amd64</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <installer.bundler>deb</installer.bundler>
            <installer.Xmx>-Xmx6G</installer.Xmx>
            <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-x64</installer.packageName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux-x86</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
                <name>Linux</name>
                <arch>i386</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <installer.bundler>deb</installer.bundler>
            <installer.Xmx>-Xmx1G</installer.Xmx>
            <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-x86</installer.packageName>
        </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>

...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                ...

                <nativeReleaseVersion>${project.version}</nativeReleaseVersion>

                <bundleArguments>
                    <mac.installerName>${installer.packageName}</mac.installerName>
                    <linux.deb.fullPackageName>${installer.packageName}</linux.deb.fullPackageName>
                    <win.installerName>${installer.packageName}</win.installerName>
                </bundleArguments>

                <bundler>${installer.bundler}</bundler>

                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>${installer.Xmx}</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>

                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        ...
```

As you can see I am using profiles to automatically choose build options base of current OS.

If your application isn't cross-platform you can simplify it:

```
<properties>
    <installer.packageName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}</installer.packageName>
</properties>

...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                ...

                <nativeReleaseVersion>${project.version}</nativeReleaseVersion>

                <bundleArguments>
                    <mac.installerName>${installer.packageName}</mac.installerName>
                    <linux.deb.fullPackageName>${installer.packageName}</linux.deb.fullPackageName>
                    <win.installerName>${installer.packageName}</win.installerName>
                </bundleArguments>

                <bundler>???</bundler>

                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        ...
```

or you can just hardcode bundle name in appropriate `*.installerName` option (options for other OS and bundle types you can find in OpenJFX sources [here](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/tree/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/windows), [here](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/tree/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/linux) or [here](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/tree/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/mac) i.e. for [mac.installerName](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/mac/MacBaseInstallerBundler.java#L152)).

Comment: Hi Maxim ;) To just set the installer/application name, you can set `<appName>SimpleAppName</appName>`